# How do I address a specific user in my comment?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

When I want to address a specific user in my comment, I put an `@` sign before his name, like this: (here's the real example)

```
@Joe Pardon me, what is 'Windows'?
```

Sometimes StackExchange does display the `@` sign when a comment is published, sometimes it doesn't. How do I know if it worked, i.e. whether the specific user in question will get notified?

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the [rules are complicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/1288) I'll answer your specific question directly. When you *@name* reply to the author of a post, the *@name* is sometimes stripped off of your comment because the author is always notified of new comments on their post.

The specific rule is #10:

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use @name to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.)

Comment: I know you said the rules are complicated, but the phrasing of  `When you @name reply to the author of a post, the @name is stripped off` suggests this is always true.  It is not stripped off when the author has also commented on their own post.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you. I fixed my answer with a direct quote, which I should have just included to begin with.